# PHP - Move items from array to array with key LIKE

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say we have array:

```
$array1 = array (
    'key1' => 1,
    'non1' => 1,
    'key2' => 1,
    'non2' => 1,
    'non3' => 1,
    'non4' => 1,
    'key3' => 1,
    'key4' => 1
);
```

How to move all the keys that have `key name` LIKE `"key"` and move them to another array.

```
$array2 = movekey('key',$array1);
```

Would give:

```
array1 = array (
    'non1' => 1,
    'non2' => 1,
    'non3' => 1,
    'non4' => 1

);

array2 = array (
    'key1' => 1,
    'key2' => 1,
    'key3' => 1,
    'key4' => 1
);
```

Comment: @YogeshSuthar That's cheating!

Comment: Write a foreach loop that checks the key and decides whether to copy the key and value to the result. What's the problem?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar haha! Nice avoidance of the filter +1

Comment: @Barmar What cheating? Can you explain? I am not getting.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar You misspelled "have" to get around SO's block on comments that just say "What have you tried?"

Comment: @Barmar Ohh, Yeah its typing mistake...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because it seemed fun, put it in function form per OP's original wish:

```
function moveKey($cmp, Array & $ar)
{
    $y = array();
    foreach($ar as $key => $value) {
        if(strpos($key, $cmp) !== false) {
            $y[$key] = $value;
            unset($ar[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $y;
}
```

and then to test the function:

```
$array1 = array (
    'key1' => 1,
    'non1' => 1,
    'key2' => 1,
    'non2' => 1,
    'non3' => 1,
    'non4' => 1,
    'key3' => 1,
    'key4' => 1
);

$a2 = moveKey('key', $array1);
echo "<pre>". print_r($array1, true) ."\n". print_r($a2, true) ."</pre>";
```

And it outputs:

```
Array
(
    [non1] => 1
    [non2] => 1
    [non3] => 1
    [non4] => 1
)

Array
(
    [key1] => 1
    [key2] => 1
    [key3] => 1
    [key4] => 1
)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

```
$array2 = array();
   foreach($array1 as $key => $val) {
     if(strpos($key,'key')!==false){
        $array2[$key] = $val; //Copy all the values that have key-name like 'key'.
        unset($array1[$key]); //Removes the copied key and value.
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  if (strpos($key, 'key') !== false) {
    $result[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (array_keys($array1) as $key) {
    if (!preg_match('/^key\d+/', $key)) {
        unset($array1[$key]);
    }
}
print_r ($array1);
```

Comment: It doesn't create the second array and using an intensive and unnecessary `preg_match` to assert the beginning position - when it was asked for `like` not "starts with" ^^ Instead of `preg_match` could use [`substr($key,0,3) == 'key'`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) (also was never specified to have digits following =] )